# Databinding a command to Context Menu with an Observable Collection

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, mvvm-light

I have a Context menu with some options.  One of the options is an Observable collection and I am having issues binding my commands in my view model to them.  I have seen many different ways to fix this issue, but none have worked because they do not specifically relate to my problem.  Here is my code first:

XAML:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewItems}" SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                    <MenuItem Header="Test" Command="{Binding TestCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}" />
                    <Separator></Separator>
                    <MenuItem Header="Status" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ObservableCollectionList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.UpdateCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.ContextMenu>
//listviewstuff here
</ListView>
```

VM:

```
public class VM : ViewModelBase
{
    public RelayCommand UpdateCommand { get; private set; }
    public Action UpdateCommandAction { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Status> ObservableCollectionList { get; set; }

    public VM()
    {
        this.UpdateCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action(() => this.UpdateCommandAction.DynamicInvoke())));
    }
}
```

Code-behind for the XAML view:

```
public partial class View
{
    public View()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var ViewDataContext = this.DataContext as VM;
        ViewDataContext .UpdateCommandAction = UpdateStatus;
    }


    private void UpdateStatus()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("test");
    }

}
```

I inserted a break point and it's not even making it to the method call.  The debug output is not showing an error for me when I run the program either.  What I don't understand is when I add this Command to the regular menu item that is NOT populated by a data bound list, it works fine.  I would appreciate a fresh pair of eyes and some insight in to how this works.

Comment: (Do you really have a property in your view model called `DataContext`? If so, that's really confusing and i would avoid it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the command to all the child items, now you bind it on the parent which will ignore it because it has child items (opens sub-menu instead).

To bind it on the children you need the `ItemContainerStyle`, create a `Setter` for the `Command` there. You will need to walk up again, probably this: `{Binding DataContext.DataContext.UpdateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}}` (not sure about the `AncestorLevel`, if it does select itself instead of the parent increase it; double `DataContext` because you bound to `DataContext.ObservableCollectionList`, assuming that binding to actually work).

Likewise there is no `SelectedItem` in a menu, you need another `Setter` for `CommandParameter`, it will simply bind to the current item, i.e. `{Binding}`.

---

**Edit:** Code example:

```
<MenuItem Header="Status"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ObservableCollectionList}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name">
  <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
      <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.DataContext.UpdateCommand,
                                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}}"/>
      <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
    </Style>
  </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked.  Unfortunately, I just realized I made an error.  I wasn't 100% accurate with you.  The context menu should be unique to each item in the listview.  So if I right click on row 2 those options should affect that row and not apply to the entire list view.  Will this code still work or do I need to make changes to the above code?

Comment: @user1296981: That mainly depends on where and how your command is implemented. You could either have a single command, then you need to pass both the row item and whatever parameter you have, or you have the command implemented as part of the item, then you just need to bind relative to the list item (as you already do by setting the `DataContext` of the menu to `PlacementTarget`), the command then should just interact with that respective item.

Comment: Well the idea is that the listview has users.  I right click a user and I can alter their status.  I'm fairly new to this so I just may have just build this wrong.  But the idea was to right click a 'busy' user and set their status to one of the options in the context sub-menu, say.. 'Available'.  I need to get the user ID AND the status ID and pass them to the method to update them both in the DB AND change the property in the app.

Comment: @user1296981: Then your user VM just needs to store the ID in a field/property, then in the constructor you directly implement your status changing command somewhat like this: `new RelayCommand(param => UpdateStatus(ID, (Status)param))`, `param` should be the passed `CommandParameter` and `ID` is just the property in the VM holding the user ID.

Comment: Well, the user ID is not a static variable.  It is in a listview of users so when i right click i need the user id associated with the context menu that I selected the status from.

Comment: @user1296981: I did not say that it's static, the command should not be static either, every instance of the user view model (one per list item) has it's own properties, including an ID and a command that updates the status using that ID.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a `List<MenuItem> MenuItems` to bind with ContextMenu ItemSource property as

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string Header { get; set; }

    public ICommand Command { get; set; }
}
```

**XAML:** and set itemContainerstyle

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" >
        <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" >
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
            </Style>
        </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ContextMenu>
```

And add as many contextmenu item you want in your ViewModel AS YOU WANT.