# How do I add a command to items in dynamically generated ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a context menu that is being populated from an ObservableCollection. I want the user to be able to click on any of those items, then a method is called passing the clicked item's text as a parameter.

I've started by following the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875966/databinding-a-command-to-context-menu-with-an-observable-collection). However, I'm getting an error in my console output and my method is not being called.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'FunctionToCall' property not found on 'object' ''MenuItem' (Name='myMenu')'. BindingExpression:Path=FunctionToCall; DataItem='MenuItem' (Name='myMenu'); target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

here is my xaml

```xml
            <MenuItem Name="myMenu" Header="display text" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
                <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding FunctionToCall, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
                    </Style>
                </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            </MenuItem>
```

And my view model code

```
    RelayCommand _command;
    public ICommand FunctionToCall
    {
        get
        {
            if (_command == null)
            {

                _command = new RelayCommand(p => this.InnerMethod(p));
            }
            return _command ;
        }
    }
    public void InnerMethod(object parameter)
    {
        ....
```

The other answer suggests playing around with adding one or two DataContexts to the Binding, I've tried this and I still get the same error although it says DataContext property cannot be found instead of FunctionToCall.

I found the definition of RelayCommand [here](http://snipplr.com/view/13642/).

Comment: I think your relative source is pointing to the dynamically created `MenuItem` and not the `MenuItem` that contain your Command. Can you check `{Binding DataContext.FunctionToCall, ElementName=myMenu}`?

Comment: Get a similar message. "System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=myMenu'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.FunctionToCall; DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how to do it.

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
```

xaml

```
<MenuItem Header="{Binding Item1}" Command="{Binding FunctionToCall}" CommandParameter="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        ICommand _cmd = new CustomCommand();
        public ICommand FunctionToCall
        {
            get { return _cmd; }
            set { _cmd = value; }
        }

        public string Item1 { get; set; }

        public ViewModel() { Item1 = "1Header"; }
    }
```

Command

```
public class CustomCommand : ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(parameter.ToString());
    }
}
```

So, in your case assuming you want to pass `Header` of `MenuItem` as parameter to your command, do following changes :

```
<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding FunctionToCall}"/>
<Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I am currently binding my MenuItem to an ObservableCollection (model property) in the view's constructor. Your solution seems to be just connecting the command to a single MenuItem.

Comment: If you would have understood the approach you wouldnt have asked this question. See the syntax and approach. I will try to update my answer though.

Comment: I was able to get it working by changing my ObservableCollection to store objects that have a method FunctionToCall. Previously my model had that method and I just had a collection of strings. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is with your binding. Use the **DataContext property of MenuItem** to actually get to the ViewModel instance

```
<MenuItem Name="myMenu" Header="display text" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
   <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
           <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.FunctionToCall, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}}"/>
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
         </Style>
   </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
 </MenuItem>
```

MenuItem will get ViewModel as DataContext. So actually we want..

> MenuItem.DataContext.FunctionToCall

Hopefully you don't need the different menu items to bind to different commands else you have to change your design a little.

**As Per Your Comments:**

You'll need a `List<MenuItem> MenuItems` to bind with ContextMenu ItemSource property as

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string Header { get; set; }

    public ICommand Command { get; set; }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" >
        <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" >
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
            </Style>
        </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ContextMenu>
```

And add as many contextmenu item you want in your ViewModel AS YOU WANT.